# plotly_selected doesn't work in R shiny with plotly

Tags: r, shiny, r-plotly, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I am developing an app with a scatter plot that color its points depending on a dropdown menu, and then, I want that when the user selects part of the data, a reactive value is changed so that I can show that subset of the points in a table.

I don't know why I am getting this warning:

> The 'plotly_selected' event tied a source ID of 'plotPCA' is not
> registered. In order to obtain this event data, please add
> `event_register(p, 'plotly_selected')` to the plot (`p`) that you wish
> to obtain event data from.

which makes my code not function correctly. The event of selecting some data in my PCA plot (scatter plot) is not captured.

Here is my code:
In my input I have:

```
...
selectInput('selectColorForPCA', 'Color by', '', selectize=TRUE),
plotlyOutput('plotPCA', width="800px", height="600px"),
...
```

And in my output:

```
      output$plotPCA <- renderPlotly({
        dat.tmp <- getPCAdata  #this is a reactive value
        if(!is.null(dat.tmp)) {
          color_group = NULL
          if(!is.null(input$selectColorForPCA) & input$selectColorForPCA != "" ){
            color_group = ~get(input$selectColorForPCA)  
          } 
          plot_ly(dat.tmp,
                x = ~PC1,
                y = ~PC2,
                color = color_group, ## color by selectColorForPCA select input
                # colors = "Dark1",
                type = 'scatter',
                mode = 'markers',
                hoverinfo = 'text',
                text = ~SampleID,
                source='plotPCA'
          )
        }
      })
```

(and this part is only run when loading the page and my intention is that when user select some points in the scatter plot, it will change the reactive value *getPCAdata*:)

```
  observeEvent(
    eventExpr = event_data("plotly_selected", source = "plotPCA"), 
    handlerExpr = {
      event.data <- event_data("plotly_selected", source = "plotPCA") ## should be plotPCA??
      if (!is.null(event.data)) {
        dat.res <- data[event.data$pointNumber + 1,]
      } else {
        dat.res <- isolate(getPCAdata())
      }
      getPCAdata <- dat.res
    }
  )
```

Please, help!